# dd and rm -r commands

Tags: rm, dd, block-device

For me, the following commands do exactly the same thing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd1

dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sd1

rm -r /dev/sd1/*
```

meaning, the result of their application is the same. Or least, that's true for the first and the third ones. Is this really the case?

Comment: How did you check whether it does the same? In pre-udev times, the last command would just have removed the device file link. But I'm not sure what it does with udev.

Comment: @celtschk, I meant `rm -r /dev/sd1/*`

Comment: What is `/dev/sd1`? `dd` does not write to a directory.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, do you think /dev/xxx can be a directory?

Comment: @Alex `find /dev -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l` Why shouldn't I?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, ok, but in this case it's an usb flash drive.

Comment: If it's not a directory, I'd expect `rm -r /dev/sd1/*` to give an error. What output do you get if you replace `rm` with `echo`?

Comment: I don't think `dd if=/dev/null of=/path/to/block/device` clears the block device at all.

Answer (score 4):

No, they do not do the same thing. `rm /dev/sda1` removes a device node, all files on the device are left intact. If we assume you made a mistake and actually meant `rm -r /mountpoint/of/dev/sda1`, then the commands will have a similar effect.

But they're still significantly different: `rm` removes inodes, making file data effectively unreachable via the filesystem. But the data is still on the device until it is overwritten by new data. You can usually recover significant portions of the data by copying the raw device data (`dd if=/dev/sda1`) and running recovery tools on that.

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1` will overwrite each byte of the device, making it *significantly* harder to recover dat from the device. Some forensic companies can still do some magic, and it's often advised to overwrite devices several times with random data to prevent that. But if you're actually worried about that, the best way to get rid of data is to phsyically destroy the device.

Comment: Also, `dd if=/dev/null` will exit immediately with no output since reading from /dev/null also gives an EOF.  You can use utilities such as `badblocks -w /dev/sda` or `shred /dev/sda1`.  Not a secure or satisfying as using a sledgehammer but good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but what does it have to do with `rm /dev/sda1` if my question is about `rm -r /dev/sd1/*`?